# When do we have to migrate from Facebook SDK for android 3.0.2Beta to 3.0?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I currently have a working Android application that is using Facebook SDK 3.0.2b and am wondering: how long can I still use this facebook SDK?

Basically, I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a date of expiration on the Beta SDK and when will that be?
2. And when the beta is expired: will my app then stop to function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a date of expiration on the Beta SDK and when will that be?

There is no hard expiration date where the SDK will stop working.

> And when the beta is expired: will my app then stop to function?

No expiration, but the beta SDK is no longer supported.  Which means, if there is a change on the server-side or anything else that may break the beta SDK, we will not be fixing it.

I recommend updating to use the official 3.0 SDK, there are only a few changes that needs to be done which can be [read about here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/upgrading-from-3.0.2.b-to-3.0/).